# E-Mail signature examination

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, sha256

If I download a signed e-mail from thunderbird, it looks like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature";     
micalg=sha-256; boundary="------------ms030600030501030208070703"

This is a cryptographically signed message in MIME format.

--------------ms030600030501030208070703
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Test



--------------ms030600030501030208070703
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
Content-Description: S/MIME Cryptographic Signature

MIAGCqGSIb3QEHAqCAMIACAQExDANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADCABkqhkiG9w0BBwEAAKCC
...
jwa1TlS4tKAFqYZWuiJj8YTDWFLakrAyA8DAgoZrBx44gbQlq4yap+s7cLF6T6Fh27zf
E2ft5vmKsXepKPLeddVtRnbMsFnnEEY4l+4s1L6xfSp1vHLRysR33jbv1tkjSeV7bu+q
VjyyMN4AAAAAAAA=
```

My goal is to verify the signature of the actual message *manually* via `openssl` without the smime option. The actual signature must be in this large base64 code:

```
$ openssl enc -base64 -d -in smime.p7s
```

But this gives me a lot of unreadable code mixed with some readable informations about my CA and so on.
How can I convert this to something readable, so that I can check the actual signature of the message-text. (After that, I want to verify it using `openssl dgst -sha256 -verify ...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the decoded base64-code to a new file with

```
$ openssl enc -base64 -d < signature > signature.dec
```

and use [der-ascii](https://github.com/google/der-ascii)

```
$ ./der2ascii -i signature.dec
```

to get the desired output.

You can also [check the plaintext-message-digest](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/176291/161637) by hand.