# What exactly is digested in an S/MIME signated-only e-mail?

Tags: digital-signature, smime, pkcs7

What exactly is digested in an S/MIME signated-only e-mail?

It's definitely not only a sha256-digest of the original message, which means that

`$ openssl dgst -sha256 <<< "Text"`

would never create the digest that is created for a S/MIME mail with the exact same "Text".

I've read and tried to understand information about this in [RFC 5751](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5751#section-3.4.3.2) (in section 3.4.3.2), but it's still unclear to me, what exactly is *digested* for a S/MIME e-mail.

How is the original message prepared and enhanced before being [hashed and encrypted](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Digital_Signature_diagram.svg)?

If I understood correctly, some CMS processing and transfer-encoding is done for preparation. Is it possible to put the entire process into easy words?

Notes like these (in [section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5751#section-3.1)) are even more confusing:

> These (three) steps are descriptive rather than prescriptive.  The
> implementer is free to use any procedure as long as the result is the
> same.

How can different e-mail-applications even work together on a basis of such vague *descriptions*?

Comment: RFC-5652 is a good start: ... [Message Digest Calculation Process](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652#section-5.4) ... [Message Digest](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652#section-11.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.4), section 5.4

> The message digest calculation process computes a message digest on
> either the content being signed or the content together with the
> signed attributes.

But you can verify the (cms-)digest of the plaintext by hand:

1. Save signed mail from Thunderbird as `Test.eml`
2. Check message digest: `$ openssl cms -in Test.eml -cmsout -print`
3. Cut out plaintext from mail and save to `Test.txt`
4. [Compare all hashes](https://github.com/JlnWntr/sha256-hash-finder) to digest from step 2: `$ lua sha256-hash-finder.lua Test.eml "4db15ae843e3 ... "`

Comment: The sha256-hash-finder repository seems to be gone. Does anyone know of a new source for this project?